# What's the idiomatic way to log values in a threading macro?

Tags: logging, clojure

In my code I use threading macros extensively.  Sometimes though I would like to log one or more of the values in the macro.  For instance,

```
(-> val
    (fn-1)
    (fn-2)
    (fn-3))
```

Here, let's say I want to log the result of `fn-2`.  How would I go about doing it?

I've tried two approaches:

- Put `trace` after `fn-2`.
- Put an anonymous function after `fn-2` like `#(do (log/debug %) %)`.

Using `trace` doesn't seem ideal since it can't be integrated with a real logger.  Rolling your own function doesn't seem ideal either.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Can you explain why rolling your own function is not ideal?

Comment: `(doto log/debug)` works with `->` but not with `->>`.

Comment: I covered this a bit in my screencast: https://curiousprogrammer.net/2017/11/20/clojure-tip-of-the-day-episode-3-threading-macros-tracing/
Mostly, it's using anonymous function or `(doto println)` for thread-first macro.
If you need more sophisticated tool I'd suggest to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a higher order `debug` function that wraps your function with whatever logic you'd like. Here is an example for simple printing:

```
(defn debug
  ([v d bmf] (debug v d bmf nil))
  ([v f before-msg-fmt amf]
   (let [r (f v)]
     (println (format before-msg-fmt v)
              (str (when amf (format amf r))))
     r)))
```

So calling it with the following functions:

```
(def fn1 identity)
(def fn2 inc)
(def fn3 (fn[x] (* x 3)))

(-> 5
    (debug fn1 "here! %s")
    (debug fn2 "old val: %s" "new val: %s")
    fn3)
```

Produces

```
here! 5 
old val: 5 new val: 6
=> 18
```